# CSS AST analyzer

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, abstract-syntax-tree

I have styles

```
.a{width: 10px;}
...
.a{width: 20px;}
```

Is is obvious that first selector unused.
I search for a tool that give me information about such places in css.
eg `getUnusedRule(styles)` -> line number at style.css, rule, selector, smth. else.

The second case is to notify about too nested selectors

```
.a .b .c .d{...}
```

`getTooLongSelectors(styles, maxNestingNum)` -> info to find place in source code

I dont want to minify output css, but need to find such places in code and fix it manually.
The point is **not to minify** code, but to make source code more accurate for the better maintenance and to prevent pile unnecessary things.

I assume it may be css AST analizer which outputs info for manual source code improvement.

I prefe **javascript** based tool, we have some js programmes in team.

Any ideas? Not just ready tools but the way of thinking welcome.

Comment: I updated my answer to share a usable nodejs script, that can handle multiple linting, and that currently validate that every selector at less than 20 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is basically a linter, perhaps you don't need to build your own. You could be interested in [CSSLint](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint). It is made with nodeJS and propose a lot of pre-coded rules.

Otherwise, you can use [reworkCSS](https://github.com/reworkcss/css) to have access to a simple AST.

```
'use strict';

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var rework = require('css');

// Usage control
if (process.argv.length != 3) {
    console.log('Usage: node index.js ./path/to/my/stylesheet.css');
    process.exit();
}

// Read a file (relative path) with node
function readFile(fileName, cb) {
    var filePath = path.join(__dirname, fileName);
    fs.readFile(filePath, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            process.exit();
        }

        cb(data);
    });
}

// A nice way to walk through every rule
function walkRules(rules, linters) {
    rules.forEach(function(rule) {
        if (rule.rules) {
            walkRules(rule.rules);
        }
        linters.forEach(function(linter){
            linter(rule);
        });
    });
}

// A custom linter
function checkRule(rule) {
    if (rule.selectors) {
        rule.selectors.forEach(function(selector) {
            if (selector.length > 20) {
                console.log('Line ' + rule.position.start.line + ': too long selector "' + selector + '"');
            }
        });
    }
}

// Main part
var fileName = process.argv[2];
readFile(fileName, function(css) {
    var ast = rework.parse(css);
    walkRules(ast.stylesheet.rules, [checkRule]);
});
```